# ansible docker env var not available in container

Tags: variables, docker, ansible, environment-variables

I am starting a docker container with ansible like this:

```
name: start the new shiny container
docker:
  name: web
  image: pneuma/web
  state: started
  detach: True
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /data/db:/var/lib/postgresql
    - /data/log:/var/log/postgresql
  env:
    DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT: "{{ deployment_env }}"
```

But the var `DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` is not available inside the container. When I try to `echo $DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` or to use somewhere else.

Anything am missing?

Comment: Could you try to show the content of the var in ansible and get back the results?
- debug: var= {{ deployment_env }}
How do you set that variable?

Comment: i set it as host var in the inventory file as follows, `ip_address  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=key_path ansible_user=username deployment_env=staging`

Comment: and the var can be seen in the docker inspect logs for the container, but for some reason not accessible inside the container

Comment: I've tried replicating what you've done and it works fine for me. See:

`$ docker exec -it 0f65 /bin/bash` ...
`root@0f65cf218c2e:/# echo $DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` ... 
`staging`

Can you post a bit more detail about how you run the ansible playbook and how you access the container?

Answer (score 1):

In an ansible 2.7.9 you are able to set the Environment (dev, staging, production) in your docker containers, (development only)

```
  - name: Build docker image
    docker_container:
      name: container_name
      image: image_name:latest
      env:
        ENV: "{{ENV}}"
      recreate: yes
      state: started
      restart: yes
```

Execute the command as below,

```
$ ansible-playbook -e "ENV=staging" main.yml
```